# Ubuntu 22.04 can't boot normally anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, virtualbox

I have been using Ubuntu for several years, however since yesterday I have been unable to boot normally anymore, instead this message shows up.

[image]

The message says something about VirtualBox which I have installed, but I'm not sure how it's related since I have not touched it for some time. Does anyone know how to fix it? I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows.

Update: I tried using the Ubuntu Live Installation USB but it did not seem to work. Next, I tried recovery mode, then choose 'root', then in the root terminal, I uninstalled virtualbox using 'sudo apt-get remove virtualbox'. I also noticed some output about no space left on device (in /usr/man/db I think), so I went to Downloads folder and deleted everything, which freed 1GB. However now the screen shows as follows.

[image]

Comment: Can you boot from the Ubuntu Live Installation USB? If so, try chroot to your internal `/` partition and uninstall virtualbox. Then try booting from the internal drive again. If everything works try reinstalling virtualbox again.

Comment: I'd suggest to try the "Recovery mode" from the grub menu instead, first!

Comment: What happens if you remove `virtualbox-modules`?

Comment: @user68186. I tried as you guys asked and I have updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: ``vboxmanage startvm ub22vm --type headless''